# Get hostname from IP with JCIFS

Tags: java, jcifs

I'm trying to understand how to get the name of a computer on my LAN given the IP address with JCIFS but I can't get anything but its IP.

The code I'm using is

```
    InetAddress addr = NbtAddress.getByName( ip ).getInetAddress();
    String test = UniAddress.getByName(ip).getHostName();
    System.out.println("IP: " + ip + " - addr: " + addr.getHostName() + " - test: " + test);
```

And the result I'm getting is

```
    IP: 10.1.2.115 - addr: 10.1.2.115 - test: 10.1.2.115
```

If instead I replace the `getHostAddress()` with `toString()` what I get is

```
    IP: 10.1.2.115 - addr: 10.1.2.115 - test: 0.0.0.0<00>/10.1.2.115
```

Where am I wrong here?

I'm testing the lib from a Mac with IP `10.1.2.117`, while the target is an Android device.

Comment: This is probably because `InetAddress`' name resolution does not do NMB lookups... And you have no DNS server running.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is on `test`, with shall give me the name but it returns me the IP...

Answer (score 2):

JCIFS stop supports Netbios name resolution on 1.3.14 version. 
You can find release notes for stopping this. https://jcifs.samba.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
    /*
      Jcifs 1.3 no longer calls NbtAddress#checkData() in 
      NbtAddress#getHostName, so you need to actively call 
      NbtAddress#getNodeType() or NbtAddress#isGroupAddress() before acquiring hostName.
    */
    UniAddress address= UniAddress.getByName(currentIp,
                    true);
    Object o = address.getAddress();
    if (o instanceof NbtAddress) {
        NbtAddress nbtAddress = (NbtAddress) o;
        // jcifs 1.3 need call this method for request netbios name.
        nbtAddress.getNodeType();
    }
    ipScan.domain = address.getHostName();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and elaborate how your answer gonna help someone in future.

Comment: Please post your explanations in answer body _NOT_ in comments. (Read my comment properly. You get edit link there)

Comment: I have added explanation to the answer, thanks for reminding me. @Shashanth

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I had the same problem with jcifs 1.3.17.  I reverted to 1.2.25 and it now works.

Answer (score -2):

Can you use the standard java api instead? If so try the following

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
String host = addr.getHostName();
```

Comment: it returned the address... unfortunately, I noticed that it was meant to act like that, since (at least from what I understood) only Windows has got Netbios name... but I can't understand how other applications che see, for instance, my phone name...